# C# objects and arrays, how to use them?

Tags: c#, arrays, object

Hello all I am working on a project for my C# class and am a bit confused I am trying to add objects to an array and then print them to the console to see if they are there but this is not working for me I am completely lost can someone perhaps show me how to go about this code below.

```
using System;
class CreateTaxPayer
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Taxpayer[] testArray = new Taxpayer[1];
        for (int i = 0; i < testArray.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.Write("Enter the social security number for taxpayer" + (i + 1) + " ");
            testArray[i].SSN = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine(testArray[i].SSN);
        }
    }

}


class Taxpayer
{
    public int SSN { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: Should be : Console.WriteLine(testArray[i].SSN);

Comment: I'm picky but you can't "add objects to an array", you can only initialize the array once it's been created

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating the array, but you also have to create the elements of the array. Like this:

```
testArray[i] = new Taxpayer();
testArray[i].SSN = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
```

Comment: omg lzydrmr you are a god I literally have been trying to figure this out for an hour THANK YOU!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;

    namespace ConsoleApp1

{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Taxpayer[] testArray = new Taxpayer[1];
            for (int i = 0; i <testArray.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.Write("Enter the social security number for taxpayer" + (i + 1) + " ");
                testArray[i] = new Taxpayer();
                testArray[i].SSN = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.WriteLine(testArray[i].SSN);
            }
        }
    }

    class Taxpayer
    {
        public int SSN { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Comment: This would have been a better answer if you explained *what* you changed and *why*